# Calculating Median Using Aggregate

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If have the following function that is used to calculate SMALL:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15; 6; Table5[Salary]/(Table5[Letter]="F") /(Table5[Level]=B2) /(Table5[[Title ]]=A2); 1); "-")
```

Which works perfectly fine when the first parameter is 15 (SMALL) or 14 (Large). But if I try to calculate the median ( replacing 15 with 12 ) the error value "-" is returned. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The median does not accept an array entry, it must be `14` or higher in the AGGREGATE to accept array entry.

You will need to use MEDIAN(IF()) as an array formula:

```
=IFERROR(MEDIAN(IF((Table5[Letter]="F")*(Table5[Level]=B2)*(Table5[[Title ]]=A2);Table5[Salary]));"-")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-
Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.